# Forward period correlations R

Tags: r, function, correlation

I'm not sure if this qualifies as question, but I need help to make my coding more efficient. I think this can be done more efficiently, I'm just really lousy writing functions and maybe seeing answer will help me improve.

Example: I have timeseries data and would like to calculate indicators Y correlation to forward period changes of my X values (multiple X). (dput is in the end).

My solution:

```
str(data.dt)
Classes ‘data.table’ and 'data.frame':  210 obs. of  3 variables:
 $ id     : chr  "X1" "X1" "X1" "X1" ...
 $ date   : Date, format: "2016-11-18" "2016-11-25" "2016-12-02" "2016-12-09" ...
 $ PX_LAST: num  2.72 2.76 2.86 2.81 2.83 ...
 - attr(*, ".internal.selfref")=<externalptr> 

#separate indicator value
y.dt <- data.dt[id=="Y"]

#add indicator as own column for each X
step1.dt <- y.dt[data.dt, on="date"]
#rename
correl.dt <-  step1.dt[, .(date=date, x_id=i.id, x_value=i.PX_LAST, y_id = id,  y_value=PX_LAST)]
#discard NAs and Y from x_id
correl.dt <- na.omit(correl.dt[x_id != "Y"])
#calculate change for each X
correl.dt[, x.chg := c(rep(NA, 1), diff(x_value, 1)), by=list(x_id)]
#create forward change by leading changes
correl.dt[, fwd.xchg := shift(x.chg, type='lead', 1), by = list(x_id)]

#create multiple Y changes to test correlations
correl.dt[, y.chg1 := c(rep(NA, 1), diff(y_value, 1)), by=list(x_id)]
correl.dt[, y.chg2 := c(rep(NA, 2), diff(y_value, 2)), by=list(x_id)]
correl.dt[, y.chg3 := c(rep(NA, 3), diff(y_value, 3)), by=list(x_id)]
correl.dt[, y.chg4 := c(rep(NA, 4), diff(y_value, 4)), by=list(x_id)]
correl.dt[, y.chg5 := c(rep(NA, 5), diff(y_value, 5)), by=list(x_id)]
correl.dt[, y.chg6 := c(rep(NA, 6), diff(y_value, 6)), by=list(x_id)]

#cbind results together
cbind(correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg1, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)],
      correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg2, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
      correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg3, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
      correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg4, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
      correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg5, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
      correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg6, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2])
```

Result, don't make sense as I have very small subset. Also I have chosen short periods of correlations to fit my subset. Help is appreciated, what is best method to test forward correlations. I'm in love with datatable, not very good at it yet, but improving. I have about 100-200 indicators to test.

Here is dput:

```
structure(list(id = c("X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", 
"X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", 
"X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", "X1", 
"X1", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", 
"X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", 
"X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X2", "X3", "X3", 
"X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", 
"X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", 
"X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X3", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", 
"X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", 
"X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", "X4", 
"X4", "X4", "X4", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", 
"X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", 
"X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", "X5", 
"X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", 
"X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", 
"X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "X6", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", "Y", 
"Y"), date = structure(c(17123L, 17130L, 17137L, 17144L, 17151L, 
17158L, 17165L, 17172L, 17179L, 17186L, 17193L, 17200L, 17207L, 
17214L, 17221L, 17228L, 17235L, 17242L, 17249L, 17256L, 17263L, 
17270L, 17277L, 17284L, 17291L, 17298L, 17305L, 17312L, 17319L, 
17326L, 17123L, 17130L, 17137L, 17144L, 17151L, 17158L, 17165L, 
17172L, 17179L, 17186L, 17193L, 17200L, 17207L, 17214L, 17221L, 
17228L, 17235L, 17242L, 17249L, 17256L, 17263L, 17270L, 17277L, 
17284L, 17291L, 17298L, 17305L, 17312L, 17319L, 17326L, 17123L, 
17130L, 17137L, 17144L, 17151L, 17158L, 17165L, 17172L, 17179L, 
17186L, 17193L, 17200L, 17207L, 17214L, 17221L, 17228L, 17235L, 
17242L, 17249L, 17256L, 17263L, 17270L, 17277L, 17284L, 17291L, 
17298L, 17305L, 17312L, 17319L, 17326L, 17123L, 17130L, 17137L, 
17144L, 17151L, 17158L, 17165L, 17172L, 17179L, 17186L, 17193L, 
17200L, 17207L, 17214L, 17221L, 17228L, 17235L, 17242L, 17249L, 
17256L, 17263L, 17270L, 17277L, 17284L, 17291L, 17298L, 17305L, 
17312L, 17319L, 17326L, 17123L, 17130L, 17137L, 17144L, 17151L, 
17158L, 17165L, 17172L, 17179L, 17186L, 17193L, 17200L, 17207L, 
17214L, 17221L, 17228L, 17235L, 17242L, 17249L, 17256L, 17263L, 
17270L, 17277L, 17284L, 17291L, 17298L, 17305L, 17312L, 17319L, 
17326L, 17123L, 17130L, 17137L, 17144L, 17151L, 17158L, 17165L, 
17172L, 17179L, 17186L, 17193L, 17200L, 17207L, 17214L, 17221L, 
17228L, 17235L, 17242L, 17249L, 17256L, 17263L, 17270L, 17277L, 
17284L, 17291L, 17298L, 17305L, 17312L, 17319L, 17326L, 17123L, 
17130L, 17137L, 17144L, 17151L, 17158L, 17165L, 17172L, 17179L, 
17186L, 17193L, 17200L, 17207L, 17214L, 17221L, 17228L, 17235L, 
17242L, 17249L, 17256L, 17263L, 17270L, 17277L, 17284L, 17291L, 
17298L, 17305L, 17312L, 17319L, 17326L), class = "Date"), PX_LAST = c(2.719, 
2.761, 2.863, 2.815, 2.831, 2.872, 2.765, 2.681, 2.692, 2.783, 
2.779, 2.795, 2.696, 2.803, 2.73, 2.807, 2.977, 2.861, 2.75, 
2.701, 2.551, 2.474, 2.538, 2.575, 2.648, 2.635, 2.475, 2.41, 
2.412, 2.373, 1.579, 1.56, 1.619, 1.73, 1.833, 1.796, 1.721, 
1.731, 1.715, 1.751, 1.782, 1.766, 1.697, 1.711, 1.607, 1.702, 
1.811, 1.761, 1.642, 1.625, 1.596, 1.494, 1.47, 1.547, 1.542, 
1.571, 1.475, 1.445, 1.4, 1.413, 1.455, 1.417, 1.38, 1.453, 1.438, 
1.345, 1.239, 1.383, 1.364, 1.431, 1.471, 1.352, 1.256, 1.211, 
1.078, 1.185, 1.231, 1.244, 1.196, 1.139, 1.075, 1.043, 1.034, 
1.085, 1.117, 1.086, 1.093, 1.012, 1.038, 1.02, 0.272, 0.24, 
0.281, 0.365, 0.314, 0.221, 0.208, 0.298, 0.338, 0.421, 0.462, 
0.412, 0.32, 0.302, 0.186, 0.356, 0.485, 0.435, 0.403, 0.328, 
0.228, 0.187, 0.253, 0.317, 0.418, 0.391, 0.368, 0.331, 0.274, 
0.268, 2.3548, 2.3572, 2.3831, 2.4675, 2.5916, 2.5373, 2.4443, 
2.4193, 2.3964, 2.4668, 2.4843, 2.4648, 2.4073, 2.4147, 2.3117, 
2.478, 2.5745, 2.5005, 2.4123, 2.3874, 2.3822, 2.2374, 2.248, 
2.2802, 2.3487, 2.3257, 2.2346, 2.2465, 2.1591, 2.1538, 0.517, 
0.534, 0.559, 0.611, 0.64, 0.615, 0.556, 0.628, 0.628, 0.699, 
0.749, 0.71, 0.665, 0.678, 0.549, 0.694, 0.774, 0.75, 0.673, 
0.605, 0.548, 0.516, 0.564, 0.587, 0.653, 0.572, 0.518, 0.514, 
0.425, 0.43, 0.8906, 0.895, 0.8999, 0.9062, 0.89, 0.8864, 0.8802, 
0.8839, 0.8964, 0.899, 0.9145, 0.9039, 0.9054, 0.9044, 0.8934, 
0.8978, 0.9041, 0.9048, 0.8979, 0.9023, 0.892, 0.8842, 0.8942, 
0.9107, 0.9121, 0.9163, 0.8944, 0.8965, 0.8995, 0.8965)), row.names = c(NA, 
-210L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .Names = c("id", 
"date", "PX_LAST"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x003c24a0>)
```

Comment: Before I try anything stupid, I have a side question for data.table connoisseurs: is there any risk associated with using this `dput` with an explicit pointer in it? Like overwriting something in memory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is something I came up with. A bit faster because a smaller number of times to assign variables, but the performance gain is not that much. Probably the simplicity of the code is the biggest advantage

```
library(dplyr)
lapply(as.list(1:6), 
     function(x) {correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y_value - shift(y_value, x), 
                                  method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][, 2]}) %>% 
do.call(cbind, .)
```

Here is a benchmark:

```
my_code <- function(){
  lapply(as.list(1:6), 
         function(x) {correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y_value - shift(y_value, x), 
                                      method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][, 2]}) %>% 
    do.call(cbind, .)

}

your_code <- function(){
  #create multiple Y changes to test correlations
  correl.dt[, y.chg1 := c(rep(NA, 1), diff(y_value, 1)), by=list(x_id)]
  correl.dt[, y.chg2 := c(rep(NA, 2), diff(y_value, 2)), by=list(x_id)]
  correl.dt[, y.chg3 := c(rep(NA, 3), diff(y_value, 3)), by=list(x_id)]
  correl.dt[, y.chg4 := c(rep(NA, 4), diff(y_value, 4)), by=list(x_id)]
  correl.dt[, y.chg5 := c(rep(NA, 5), diff(y_value, 5)), by=list(x_id)]
  correl.dt[, y.chg6 := c(rep(NA, 6), diff(y_value, 6)), by=list(x_id)]

  #cbind results together
  cbind(correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg1, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)],
        correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg2, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
        correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg3, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
        correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg4, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
        correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg5, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2],
        correl.dt[, cor(fwd.xchg, y.chg6, method='spearman', use='pairwise'), by=.(x_id)][,2])
}

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(my_code(), your_code())
## Unit: milliseconds
##        expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
##   my_code()  8.818589  9.160749  9.47846  9.293391  9.605331 13.12389   100
## your_code() 11.068776 11.436789 11.98425 11.600102 11.926878 16.94066   100
```

Comment: Thanks, my problem is doing everything step-by-step, so lapply, map and other useful shortcuts are good.